# How to change SHOW GRANTS Title in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
MySQL [Database]> show grants for "user"@"%";
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@%                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to alter the `Grants for user@%` title, but the following statements throw an error:

```
show grants for "user"@"%" AS TEST;
show grants AS TEST for "user"@"%";
select * from (show grants AS Test for "user"@"%") as SUB;
```

I want to get the following result somehow:

```
MySQL [Database]> show grants for "user"@"%" AS TEST;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| TEST                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The reason why I want to alter the title is, because the PHP framework I'm using, is converting the database query to an object and `Grants for user@%` would be object variable/field, which I need to call, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: You can't change it, you just deal with what it gives you. The label is largely irrelevant and can be ignored. Can you fetch your rows as plain arrays instead of associative ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the result heading of SHOW GRANTS, you can piece together the information from tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

- [USER_PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-privileges-table.html)
- [SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/schema-privileges-table.html)
- [TABLE_PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-privileges-table.html)
- [COLUMN_PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-privileges-table.html)

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to write the SQL query to do that.